# Trying to change a graphic in PHP based on wordpress custom-post taxonomy name

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

http://pastebin.com/R73j4rZX

Hi, I have a .php file thats set up my main page, checking the GPS location, title, description etc for custom blog posts (post_type=listing) and placing nodes on the theme map shown here; http://jeremynative.com/onthissite/

What I want to do is change the red dot for each site depending on a custom field within each post
for example (in my crude code)

```
if (listing_type == 'settlement'){ 

icon : "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/SETTLEMENT-marker.png" 

}
```

At the moment, each node is told to be assigned a red dot graphic on line 62 of the code. I'd want to expand that to if statements depending on the listing_title, but I'm having trouble telling this .php code to check the post/listing for it's 'listing_type' and assign a graphic based on that.

If I could figure it out for one, I could add others and populate the map dynamically to show settlement sites, missionary sites, burials etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like below to modify it for the entire page

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['et-listing-type'] == 'settlement'){ 
echo 'icon : "' . echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/SETTLEMENT-marker.png"';
}else{
echo 'icon : "' . echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/red-marker.png"';
} ?>
```

But I think the best way to do it would be to modify your javascript function `et_add_marker` to take an extra argument, and then use that argument to determine the icon.

---

**EDIT**
javascript would be change number of parameters in the function definition on line 41:

```
    function et_add_marker( marker_order, marker_lat, marker_lng, marker_description, markericon ){
```

Use the variable on line Line 62:

```
icon : markericon
```

Add a placeholder to the printf function that calls et_add_marker end of Line 114 to

```
<!-- .et_marker_info -->\',%7$s',
```

and add `,$et_marker_icon` to the end of 120 to pull the value into the function

you set `$et_marker_icon` similar to `$et_location_lng` 106

Comment: Hi Jdow, I had thought of changing et_add_marker function to create an icon to cover or replace the current red one, knowing that might be the best option as it already includes the while loop to check the ID for each post. I didn't know how to add the additional argument, along with formatting the new icon in the position of the old one. Is this code you suggest meant to be placed outside of the original place where the icon is initiated? (IE not on line 61)

Comment: Would it be difficult to modify the current et_add_marker function to check the post's custom field/taxonomy of et-listing-type or listing_type, then give it an icon based on that?

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a javascript developer, there may be bugs in my suggestion, but it should point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you, I managed to implement everything but the listing_type check itself as you recommended. 

 $et_marker_icon on line 106

I suppose I would create icons based on the listing_type name, then have the function somehow read the listing_type within the loop and tell it to assign that icon PNG. That's where I'm at

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track, Unfortunately I don't know enough about wordpress or your current implementation to help you on that one, but I would start with the get_post_meta() function. If you wanted to test it, try manually assigning the variable to settlement marker. Please accept/upvote my answer if that's helped